# Scraping html generated by javascript with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, htmlsession

My code:

```
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
result = r.html.find('.YD-Header')
```

I am able to scrape it like this if class name = "YD-Header"

But I would like to scrape HTML element with class name:

```
 <td>
 class="Fw(500) Ta(end) Pstart(10px) Miw(60px)"
 </td>
```

My code doesn't find anything if I use:

```
 result = r.html.find('.Fw(500)')
```

How can I find this class (class name consists of blanks and parentheses)?

Comment: You really want to avoid using classes like the above which are prone to change. This looks much like a technique Yahoo Finance uses. Better is to look for a relationship between elements/attributes that avoids these.

Answer (score 0):

CSS requires that characters like ( and ) are escaped with the \ character, so for classes with those names you end up with selectors like .Pstart(20px).

The issue here is that JavaScript strings also treats \ as the escape character. The JS string '.Pstart(20px)' represents the string .Pstart(20px), which is again not a valid CSS selector as the parenthesis aren't escaped.

The solution is to double escape the classes: the JS string '.Pstart\(20px\).Pstart\(40px\)--md' accurately represents the .Pstart(20px).Pstart(40px)--md CSS selector.

Comment: You should probably use this feature: `this` to write things like `.Pstart\(20px\).Pstart\(40px\)--md` because it makes them look clearer